# Integrating BuildFire with Firebase api

Tags: firebase, buildfire

I would like to know or have sample of integrating the api key generated from firebase to buildfire mobile app. (Not using buildfire.js) Is there any other way to integrate the api key without having to code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate using BuildFireStore which integrate with Firebase’s Firestore. https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Buildfire-Firebase-Integration
You can get this don’t through the BuildFire dev portal https://dev.buildfire.com this will integrate with BuildFire with authentication and user tagging.

That being said, each plugin still needs to be coded to integrate with your own database and structure.

On a final note, generally people will on code the plugins they need to host on their firebase database. The rest can stay within the BuildFire CMS since no integrations are need for this like a Folder Plugin.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any other more secure way? Rest api?

Comment: The custom user auth is all done server to server. It is very safe. Unless you do not like Firebase REST API's. You should be able to secure read/write privileges on firebase. That being said you can also use any other database system you'd like